# query not working - React Native app + Xcode

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, react-native, healthkit

My HealthKit query is not working.
I am trying to get the steps count and I am confused on which part of my code is in-correct.
When I build the app, it either throws "updateStepsCount is not a recognised objc method" or "Unhandled promise rejection".
Where am I going wrong here!!!

Controller.swift:

```
@objc
  func updateStepsCount(_ statisticsCollection: HKStatisticsCollection, _ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                        rejecter reject: @escaping (RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void) {
      
      let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
      
      let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())
      
      let anchorDate = Date.mondayAt12AM()
      
      let daily = DateComponents(day: 1)
      
      let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
      
      let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: stepType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum, anchorDate: anchorDate, intervalComponents: daily)

          healthStore.execute(query)
    
    struct Step {
        let id = UUID()
      var count: Int?
        var date: Date?
    }
      let endDate = Date()
      
    statisticsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate!, to: endDate) { (statistics, stop) in
          
          let count = statistics.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: .count())
          let steps = Int(count ?? 0)
        
        var stepCount = [Step]()
        var tempStepCount = Step(count: steps, date: Date())
          
        tempStepCount.count = steps
        tempStepCount.date = startDate
        stepCount.append(tempStepCount)
      }
    resolve(Step())
  }
```

Controller.m

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(updateStepsCount: (HKStatisticsCollection)someStatisticsCollection
                  resolve: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
```

JS side:

```
 clickHandler = async() => {
    const login = HealthkitController.updateStepsCount()
    .then(result => console.warn(result));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your `updateStepsCount` method requires argument `statisticsCollection` as a first param. When you try to call `updateStepsCount()` in js it converts to `updateStepsCount` in objc bridge but you don't have this method you have `updateStepsCount:` and this one has a param so you have to pass a param.

> NOTE: React Native bridge works only with standard JSON types so input parameters can be standard types (number, string, dictionary etc.) but you can also use `RCTConvert` to map they to custom ones. Result of your promise must be standard type as well so you can not return your struct. (https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#argument-types)